# Static validation methods WCF

Tags: wcf, static-methods

If I have some WCF methods like

```
GetEmployeeDetailsResponse GetEmployeeDetails(GetEmployeeDetailsRequest request)
GetCustomerDetailsResponse GetEmployeeDetails(GetCustomerDetailsRequest request)
```

and I need to perform input validation on the Request objects, can I use static methods?
Many of the validations will be common like Request object should not be null and employee id/customer ID (in the request message) should not be 0 and things like that. I am guessing that since the Request objects themselves are separate objects, passing them into a static method should not cause any thread-safety issues.
I am using Per-Call services.

Thanks 
Vikas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

But - think about situations when you will verify request #1, and will receive request#2 **before** request#1 will be done. 
If your static method will do something common for both of this requests, you can find yourself thinking about `locks`, ...

Using some kind of inspectors, like  [IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx) , will be more
right choice for such things - IMO.

Comment: In my case the static method do not have any shared state or common data fields. They operate on the individual 'Request' objects and their fields that are received in the service operation. Can I say I am good to go then?